# How to Open a UITableView from a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, storyboard

I am using a custom UICollectionView that has many cells and each cell has a button near the bottom.  What I want to do is have a table list of numbers display when a given cell button is clicked.  The table list will be a simple list of numbers [1-n], with n varying on the indexPath (i.e. section and row) of the cell.

What I'm trying to figure out:

1) how do I open a uitableview whenever a given cell's button is clicked?
2) does the uitableview I open have to take up the whole screen?

Basically I do not want it to take up the whole screen (since I'm locked in Landscape mode and that would look weird) so I'm wondering how to control the width and height of the tableView?

Sorry for the noob iOS question, thanks for any help!

(the `flipScore` button is where I want to open the uitableview from

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 4;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
    numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _scoresList.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MainCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView
                                      dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ScoreCell"
                                      forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.layer.borderWidth=1.5f;
    cell.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    [[cell flipScore] addTarget:self action:@selector(flipScore:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    long row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *score;
    NSInteger scoreVal;

    //---------------------------------
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case PLAYER_1:
            score = [NSString stringWithString:_player_1_Scores[row]];
            scoreVal = [score intValue];
            if (scoreVal < 0) {
                // if score negative, player did not make that hand
                [cell.flipScore setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                NSString *substr = [score substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, ([score length]-1))];
                cell.flipScore.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24];
                [cell.flipScore setTitle:substr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else {
                [cell.flipScore setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                cell.flipScore.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:38];
                [cell.flipScore setTitle:score forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            break;
        case PLAYER_2:
            score = [NSString stringWithString:_player_2_Scores[row]];
            scoreVal = [score intValue];
            if (scoreVal < 0) {
                // if score negative, player did not make that hand
                [cell.flipScore setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                NSString *substr = [score substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, ([score length]-1))];
                cell.flipScore.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24];
                [cell.flipScore setTitle:substr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else {
                [cell.flipScore setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                cell.flipScore.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:38];
                [cell.flipScore setTitle:score forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            break;
        case PLAYER_3:
            score = [NSString stringWithString:_player_3_Scores[row]];
            scoreVal = [score intValue];
            if (scoreVal < 0) {
                // if score negative, player did not make that hand
                [cell.flipScore setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                NSString *substr = [score substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, ([score length]-1))];
                cell.flipScore.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24];
                [cell.flipScore setTitle:substr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else {
                [cell.flipScore setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                cell.flipScore.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:38];
                [cell.flipScore setTitle:score forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            break;

        case PLAYER_4:
            score = [NSString stringWithString:_player_4_Scores[row]];
            scoreVal = [score intValue];
            if (scoreVal < 0) {
                // if score negative, player did not make that hand
                [cell.flipScore setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                NSString *substr = [score substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, ([score length]-1))];
                cell.flipScore.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24];
                [cell.flipScore setTitle:substr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else {
                [cell.flipScore setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                cell.flipScore.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:38];
                [cell.flipScore setTitle:score forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)flipScore:(id)sender event:(id)event {

    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:_collectionView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    NSLog(@"Flip Score: %ld, Row: %ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row);

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case PLAYER_1:
            //TODO: open uiTableView with list of scores
            break;
        case PLAYER_2:
            //TODO: open uiTableView with list of scores
            break;
        case PLAYER_3:
            //TODO: open uiTableView with list of scores
            break;
        case PLAYER_4:
            //TODO: open uiTableView with list of scores
            break;
    }

    [_collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UITableView` does not need to take up the whole screen.
You can set the frame of the tableview and set `hidden = YES` or `=NO` depending on whether you want to show it or not.

Comment: How about adding it?  Any sample code?  I haven't done this before and am wondering what the main steps are.  I've looked around some bit and and am wondering what it even takes to just display/open the view?  Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KGModal](https://github.com/kgn/KGModal). You can take a UITableViewController to show you data then simply add your tableview using

```
- (void)showWithContentViewController:(UIViewController *)contentViewController andAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Also don't worry about Orientation, KGModal is smart enough to handle that for you :)

Hope this would work.

Comment: This seems like it might work, let me investigate other avenues first and might come back to this.  Mainly I want to see what type of effot it is to simply make the calls myself.  Thx

Comment: just add it to the xib/storyboard